# Python 3 Selenium Run Multiple Browsers Simultaneously

Tags: python, selenium, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to run multiple browsers at the same time with Selenium.
All processes start but don't execute passed functions correctly.

My Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# function that creates driver
driver = self.create_driver()

pool.apply_async(launcher.launch_browser, driver)
```

The launch_browser function is a different Python script that is supposed to run but only a Browser window is opened. (yes, I imported the external script as a module)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open new browser windows the same way you open the first one, with the same or different browsers:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstBrowser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        self.secondBrowser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def gotopage(self):
        self.firstBrowser.get("https://www.google.com/")
        self.secondBrowser.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")


bot = Bot()
bot.gotopage()
```